# How to hide a column in a row in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering if there is a way to hide a specific column from a row. I have a table (named as docs) something like this below,

```
  File No     Upload

   test1       doc1
   test2       doc2
```

My modified table should look something like this

```
  File No     Upload

   test1        
   test2       doc2
```

I know how to hide a column. But if there is a specific column value in a specific row has to be hidden, then how to do it? Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Check this. [VPD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG007)

Comment: decode(columnName, 'what you want to hide', null, columnName)

Comment: You can hide the contents of a specific cell by using `case()` or similar switch statements with a hard-coded value. But if you want something more configurable you should use Fine-Grained Access Control policies, as @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz suggests

Answer (score 1):

Just use `nullif()`:

```
select fileno, nullif(upload, 'doc1')
from docs;
```

`case` would be a more general solution for more values.

If you are identifying the value using both columns:

```
select fileno,
       (case when fileno = 'test1 and upload = 'doc1' then NULL else upload end) as upload
from docs;
```

If you want this generally available, then create a view with the logic (say `v_docs`) and have all users use the view instead of the base table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CASE`.

```
SELECT fileno, case when upload = 'doc1' then null else upload end AS upload
FROM tbl
```